# How to validate input like in React.propTypes for the input of custom functions?

Tags: validation, reactjs

I really like to enforce/validate data based on the React style but I find very hard to decouple their classes from the library to be more generic. How I might do it? (Notice that is not form validation)

I give an object to a function and I want that function to validate that input based on a "schema":

```js
 function(input){
      validate(input, {
           test: Validator.Number
      })
 }
```

Notice that it also enables nested arrays and objects validation. http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

I've tried https://github.com/molnarg/js-schema but extends native objects `Number.min(0).max(5),`

Comment: Sorry about that.. What should I don then? Anyway I think it might help other people.

Comment: Should I ask it "How to validate like React prop types..." in order to not be closed?

Comment: I've updated my question... If nobody reply here I will put there.

Comment: Much better. I've retracted my close vote, and I'll clean up the comments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly and seems to be more related to javascript and how compose and modularize javascript code, you could use browserify  http://browserify.org/, declare your model (schema) in a js file and in your react file include it...them call Duck(myDuck) and check the boolean result for validate inputs..if it's true add to your state (or whatever you want) and if its fail process this...

you could try mixing too facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html but it seems more related to "extend" functionalities in your component, although I think you could use them perfectly...

```
  var schemas = {DuckValidation : schema({age: ....}), CatValidation : schema()}

  var myComponent = React.createClass({
     mixins: [schemas], // Use the mixin

     onSubmitCat: function(obj) {
        this.CatValidation(obj) ? this.sendToServer(obj) : this.showError()
        return false
     },

     render: function() {
       .....
     }
 });
```

although I think than use browserify is better option if you don't want extend the functionalities of your component (check than you use this.CatValidation because your component is extended with that method)

Comment: Is not this what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a library or a way to validate some input for some functions. Just generic functions, doesn't have nothing to do with React.js. I would like the library to be like React.js PropsTypes.

Answer (score 0):

PropTypes were actually pretty well isolated back then. There's been a small update recently, and you should be able to use them even more independently now: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/core/ReactPropTypes.js

Here's the usage: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/core/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L947

Tell me if that helps!

Comment: I will check it out later, now I'm a little busy with other stuff so i can't tell if it works or not (: hope I don't forget to reply to you later